# does laravel request cycle repeats on every page refresh?

Tags: laravel, lifecycle

As Laravel as described its life cycle. So I need to clear that if the complete life cycle gets repeat on every page refresh and action on the laravel application?

Also is the request reaches to routes at the end or in the beginning?

Please Clear my confusion....

Comment: yes laravel cycle repeats on every request

Comment: Also you can expect the route to run as the "last middleware" so in the end (though some middleware might actually run after the request route).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the life cycle is being processed for every request to the application.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/lifecycle

A request will be sent through the middlewares and then will be sent to the Router.

```
/**
 * Send the given request through the middleware / router.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendRequestThroughRouter($request)
{
    $this->app->instance('request', $request);

    Facade::clearResolvedInstance('request');

    $this->bootstrap();

    return (new Pipeline($this->app))
                ->send($request)
                ->through($this->app->shouldSkipMiddleware() ? [] : $this->middleware)
                ->then($this->dispatchToRouter());
}
```